# How do I align hyperlinks using HTML?

Tags: html, alignment, anchor

I have 3 hyper links. I would like one to be aligned left, one aligned in the center, and the last aligned to the right; all on one line, symmetrically. I've centered headings using ALIGN="CENTER" etc. But after some research i found out that element (A) doesn't recognize that as a command necessarily. So, what is the proper method for getting these hyperlinks to align the way i need? This is literally my first day using HTML or any kind of programming language for that matter. Your help and patience is appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: Post the code you have tried in your question please.

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to this depending on markup, but the most common approaches involve using floats or absolute positioning. Since you haven't provided any code to start with, I'll just give you a basic example.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <a class="pull-left">Left Link</a>
    <a>Center Link</a>
    <a class="pull-right">Right Link</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper { text-align: center; }
.pull-left { float: left; }
.pull-right { float: right; }
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x4hrgdaL/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do that, a table would be one, but this way is quick way. Not responsive however.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cx34wbf4/)

```css
.hyperlink {

  display: inline-block;

}

.one {

  text-align: left;

  width: 30%;

}

.two {

  text-align: center;

  width: 30%;

}

.three {

  text-align: right;

  width: 30%;

}
```

```html
<div class="hyperlinkContainer">
  <a class="hyperlink one" href="#">Hyperlink 1</a>
  <a class="hyperlink two" href="#">Hyperlink 2</a>
  <a class="hyperlink three" href="#">Hyperlink 3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

According to my understanding:your code looks like the following:

```
<a align="left">link1</a> <a align ="center">link 2</a> <a align="right">link 3</a>
```

If u want the alignment of the links to be in a format which you have mentioned,include the content in  tag.

Ex:

```
 <div align="left"><a>link1</a></div>
```

Comment: "align" - we are no longer in 1997 :)

Comment: Yes.it has been discarded in html5 though. ;)